# java: Get row data from popupmenu actionListener event

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, popupmenu

I'm having a little scenario here that maybe a duplicate. I have JTable where i show some data, i have a mouselistener that listens for right clicks on the table and displays a popup menu with one menuitem. My goal is that when the user clicks the menuitem, i get the values from the table and feed them into a custom dialog which has some fill in fields, so that the user doesn't have to feed the whole dialog by hand since i will feed the dialog with the values selected on the table. but my problem is that the menuitem actionevent doesn't have a way of getting the point so that i can use `table.getRowAt()`. i have read another comment (check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4122082/1788917) where i have been told that i can save the row number in a variable that can then be accessed by the actionlistener for the menuitem.

i want it to look like this

```
theScrollPane.getViewport().add(myJTable, null);
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(clickMe);

menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    menuItemActionPerformed(e);
}
});

MouseListener popupListener = new PopupListener(); 
popupMenu.add(menuItem);
myJTable.addMouseListener(popupListener);

protected void menuItemActionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    // what to do here to get the table row data
    // and send it to my custom dialog via it's constructor ???
}


// a simple nested class for the popup
class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int row = myJTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        int selectedRow = myJTable.getSelectedRow();

        // just to make sure the popup appears only where the row is 
                    // selected
        if (row == selectedRow) {
            showPopup(e);
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        int row = myJTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        int selectedRow = myJTable.getSelectedRow();
        if (row == selectedRow) {
            showPopup(e);
        }
    }

    private void showPopup(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
        popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
```

}

so my question is, is saving the row number the only way that i can do this or is there a better way?

Comment: please post the material related to your question instead of copy-pasting the entire code.

Comment: i have not even used my code, this is just something small to highlight what i'm looking for

Comment: Why to take a row and edit in the popup? You can make the `JTable` row editable and edit there itself. Or is there any other thing that you are doing other than editing in the popup.

Comment: @Che I have a custom dialog that let's the user put his details (name, email e.t.c) then chooses a room to reserve (using filters like suite, capacity e.t.c). but I want also that when he selects the a room from the table, i can just feed the dialog with room details so that the user only fills his/her personal details. that's all, the room table is not editable!

Comment: @Che `Why to take a row and edit in the popup?`, because JTables view could be  with removed columns contains synchonizations data or unique ID etc., by default theses columns aren't, never will be visible on the JTables view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i have read another comment (check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4122082/1788917) where i have been told that i can save the row number in a variable

You read the wrong comment.

If you read the answer above that link (ie. the one with 7 votes) you will see the solution is to select the row you clicked on BEFORE showing the popup menu. Then in your menu item Action you can reference

```
table.getSelectedRow();
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried your case referring to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558293/java-swing-jtable-right-click-menu-how-do-i-get-it-to-select-aka-highlight-t) and I am able to get the row and show it in a `JDialog`. I just modified my old code to do this. I haven't thoroughly tested.

[image: Pop Up In JTable]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class AllTableExample {


    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JTable allTable;
    private AllTableModel allTableModel;

    public AllTableExample() {

        List<TableData> data = new ArrayList<TableData>();
        data.add(new TableData("John1", "A", "Maths", "Hellen1"));
        data.add(new TableData("John2", "A", "Maths", "Hellen2"));
        data.add(new TableData("John3", "A", "Maths", "Hellen3"));
        data.add(new TableData("John4", "A", "Maths", "Hellen4"));
        data.add(new TableData("John5", "A", "Maths", "Hellen5"));

        allTableModel = new AllTableModel(data);
    }

    public void createUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        tabbedPane.add("All", getAllTablePanel());

        frame.add(tabbedPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Table Model Example.");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getAllTablePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        allTable = new JTable(allTableModel);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(allTable);
        panel.add(scroll);

        allTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                int r = allTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if (r >= 0 && r < allTable.getRowCount()) {
                    allTable.setRowSelectionInterval(r, r);
                } else {
                    allTable.clearSelection();
                }

                int rowindex = allTable.getSelectedRow();
                if (rowindex < 0)
                    return;
                if (e.getComponent() instanceof JTable) {
                    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                    int selectedRow = allTable.getSelectedRow();

                    dialog.setTitle("Edit Row: " + selectedRow);

                    TableData data = ((AllTableModel) allTable.getModel()).getTableData().get(selectedRow);
                    List<TableData> tempData = new ArrayList<TableData>();
                    tempData.add(data);

                    AllTableModel tempModel = new AllTableModel(tempData);

                    JTable table = new JTable(tempModel);
                    dialog.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            });

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AllTableExample().createUI();
            }
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }

}


class AllTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    List<TableData> tableData = new ArrayList<TableData>();

    Object[] columnNames = {"Name", "Grade", "Subject", "Staff"};

    public AllTableModel(List<TableData> data) {

        tableData = data;
    }

    public List<TableData> getTableData() {
        return tableData;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column].toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return tableData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        TableData data = tableData.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return data.getName();
        case 1:
            return data.getGrade();
        case 2:
            return data.getSubject();
        case 3:
            return data.getStaff();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

}

class TableData {

    private String name;
    private String grade;
    private String subject;
    private String staff;

    public TableData(String name, String grade, String subject, String staff) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.staff = staff;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    public String getStaff() {
        return staff;
    }
    public void setStaff(String staff) {
        this.staff = staff;
    }
}
```

Note: Store the row number of the table on which the pop-up opened such that after the changes in the popup dialog we have to update the original row.