# Populating a table in a GUI with MVC architecture

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, user-interface, jtable

I have re-structured my GUI according to the MVC pattern, but I am not sure how to populate a JTable in my view. So far, my code is:

VIEW:

```
public class GUIview extends JFrame {
...
    // set Table Inputs info
public void setTableInfo(List<Object[]> listTable) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listTable.size(); i++) {
        Object[] tempArray = listTable.get(i);
        ((DefaultTableModel) getTableModel()).insertRow(i, tempArray);
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER.

```
public class GUIcontroller {
...
       m_view.setTableInfo(m_model.getList());
```

MODEL

```
public class GUImodel {
...
    public List<Object[]> getList() {
        return resultsList;
    }
```

I would like to code as close as possible to MVC. Is this the most suitable approach? I mean, the View should not contain code just for rendering the view. I am thinking about move the "for" loop to the controller, and then just call a view-function for the insertRow. Is is better?

Answer (score 1):

In the `GUI` you just have to set the model to the `JTable` and the `TableModel` should do all the data related issues like adding rows, removing rows, setting values, updating cell values.

You can go through this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224777/cell-validation-in-jtable/16232868#16232868).

Comment: Thanks Che. I have reviewed this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15658573/2373397) , but where should I place the classes "TableData" and "AllTableModel" ?? Do I have to create a proper file for them? Or maybe turn them into inner classes of my "GUIview" class?

Comment: No for Inner class. Create a separate class for `TableModel`. Populate data in the model either getting it from the file (say a separate `fileIO` class) or write a method in the model that returns dummy data in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add elements to model and if everything is setup ok, table should be filled on screen.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit in more detail? I have thought about using jGoodies Binding framework, is that what you say? Thx Marko Frelih

Comment: Well, according to [JTable docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html), first you should subclass TableModel, which containts data itself. Then you apply model to JTable via setModel and then you subclass cell renderer.

Comment: mmm, that sounds interesting and quite logical. Let´s investigate... Thanks again Marko Frelih